# vim - using cabbrev with '!'

Tags: vim, command-line, mapping

I have been using the following `cabbrev` for ages (it doesn't matter what 'SafeQuitAll()' actually does here);-

```
cabbrev qa <C-r>=(getcmdtype()==#':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'call <sid>SafeQuitAll()' : 'qa')<cr>
```

This works well, but I now want to add support for a '!' (ie, ':qa!'), so I added a parameter to SafeQuitAll() to pass in the '!' status, and added an extra `cabbrev`, which gives me this;-

```
cabbrev qa <C-r>=(getcmdtype()==#':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'call <sid>SafeQuitAll(0)' : 'qa')<cr>
cabbrev qa! <C-r>=(getcmdtype()==#':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'call <sid>SafeQuitAll(1)' : 'qa!')<cr>
```

...except this does not work. The ':qa' version still works fine, but as soon as I press '!' when entering 'qa!', the command line expands to;-

```
:call <SNR>2_SafeQuitAll(0)!
```

ie, the `cabbrev` for 'qa!' is being masked by the `cabbrev` for 'qa' and entering '!' is causing the first `cabbrev` to trigger. I have tried all sorts of combinations of syntax to try and work around this but no luck. In particular, I tried this but it makes no difference (I'm pretty sure `getcmdline()` is always returning an empty string, which I don't understand);-

```
cabbrev qa <C-r>=(getcmdtype()==#':' && getcmdpos()==1 && getcmdline()!~?'qa!' ? 'call <sid>SafeQuitAll(0)' : 'qa')<cr>
```

So, I suppose the crux of the issue is that '!' is being seen as a command terminator (am I wrong?), hence the premature `cabbrev` execution. Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Abbreviations are generally thought of as expanding on `<space>` if you want the space after the abbreviation or `<C-]>` if you don't. But those are actually special cases. Abbreviations actually expand on *non-keyword characters* (like `!` or `,`, etc.), which is what's happening, here.

This creates a kind of race condition between your two abbreviations. `qa!` expands `qa` so `qa!` can't be expanded.

I am not aware of a way to avoid that behavior but that's one reason to use mappings instead of abbreviations: `qa` and `qa!` being two distinct mappings, you can be confidant that pressing `qa!` won't clash with `qa`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I would normally define a command but in this case, I really need to override the standard command otherwise keyboard-chaos will ensue